# Post request from ios interpretted as GET on server

Tags: php, ios, swift, post

I have been working on an iOS app and it had been working fine since today.

Today my app started showing no data and when I checked I found out that when I send a request to the server for the data, it says that my request is a get request. In server I have a check that only allows post request. Here is the code for that:

```
if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0){
    // throw new Exception('Request method must be POST!');
    echo json_encode(["status"=> "0", "message"=> "Request must be post request", "Server Var" => $_SERVER], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    die();
}
```

From iOS app, I am sending a post request. Here is the code for that:

```
let param = state ? "\(BASE_URL)user/stateslist.php": "\(BASE_URL)user/countieslist.php"
let dic = ["apikey": APIKEY]



let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: param)
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
    request.httpBody = json
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let tache = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    print(response)
    if let antwort = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        let code = antwort.statusCode
        print("Code is \(code)")
        guard error == nil else {
            completion(error, nil)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            completion(error, nil)
            return
        }
        var counties = [StateCounty]()
        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                print(json)
                if let data = json["data"] as? NSArray{
                    for  user in data{
                        if let item = user as? NSDictionary{
                            let user = StateCounty(dic: item)
                            counties.append(user)
                        }
                    }
                    completion(nil, counties)
                }
                else{
                    completion(nil, nil)
                }
            }
            else{
                completion(nil, nil)
            }

        } catch let error {
            completion(error, nil)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
print("HTTP METHOD \(tache.currentRequest?.httpMethod)")//this says post
tache.resume()
```

But this is the result I get from the API. The code provided above is executed for PHP and this is the output:

```
["message": Request must be post request, "status": 0, "Server Var": {
    "DOCUMENT_ROOT" = "/home/u562977278/domains/domain/public_html";
    HTTPS = on;
    "HTTP_ACCEPT" = "application/json";
    "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" = "gzip, deflate";
    "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" = "en-us";
    "HTTP_HOST" = "host";
    "HTTP_USER_AGENT" = "Gotyour6/1.2.6 CFNetwork/1107.1 Darwin/19.0.0";
    "LSPHP_ProcessGroup" = on;
    PATH = "/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin";
    "PHP_SELF" = "/gotyour6/user/countieslist.php";
    "QUERY_STRING" = "";
    "REMOTE_ADDR" = "103.255.5.84";
    "REMOTE_PORT" = 7083;
    "REQUEST_METHOD" = GET;
    "REQUEST_SCHEME" = https;
    "REQUEST_TIME" = 1588750834;
    "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" = "1588750834.773307";
    "REQUEST_URI" = "/foldername/user/countieslist.php";
    "SCRIPT_FILENAME" = "/home/u562977278/domains/domainname/public_html/gotyour6/user/countieslist.php";
    "SCRIPT_NAME" = "/gotyour6/user/countieslist.php";
    "SCRIPT_URI" = "https://domainname/gotyour6/user/countieslist.php";
    "SCRIPT_URL" = "/gotyour6/user/countieslist.php";
    "SERVER_ADDR" = "46.17.175.194";
    "SERVER_ADMIN" = "";
    "SERVER_NAME" = "servername";
    "SERVER_PORT" = 443;
    "SERVER_PROTOCOL" = "HTTP/1.1";
    "SERVER_SOFTWARE" = LiteSpeed;
    "SSL_CIPHER" = "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256";
    "SSL_CIPHER_ALGKEYSIZE" = 128;
    "SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE" = 128;
    "SSL_PROTOCOL" = "TLSv1.3";
    "X-LSCACHE" = on;
    "X_SPDY" = HTTP2;
}]
```

I am not sure if it is a problem with the client side or the server side. But with further debugging using Postman, I found out that it works with Postman but not from iOS. Same request gives expected results and treats the request as POST request but not the same case with iOS.

I hope I can get a better understanding of the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be an error with HTTP method in the code that you provided.
You can check the actual http request if you run app on simulator and use Charles or WireShark to trace the request. Or on device using Charles or other proxies.
You should see something like this:

```
    POST /user/stateslist.php HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost:8080
Content-Type    application/json
Accept  application/json
User-Agent  MyPlayground123456789/1 CFNetwork/1125.2 Darwin/19.4.0
Content-Length  19
Accept-Language en-us
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Connection  keep-alive
```